# building a B2B site with Broadleaf Commerce

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

last week, my boss asked me to find a java based open source which can build a B2B site . up to now, I have found broadleaf commerce and apache ofbiz. i have decided to use boradleaf commerce because broadleaf is simple and easy to be customized. now I wonder if broadleaf commerce can be used to build a B2B site in the short time? can you tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seongju, this question is likely not ideal for stack overflow as"building a b2b site" means different things to different people.   I encourage you to take this question to the [Broadleaf Commerce Forums](http://forum.broadleafcommerce.org)

I work for Broadleaf Commerce and the platform out of box is useful for some B2B scenarios.

The main benefits are that it support many advanced pricing concerns for B2B implementations via the programmable [Dynamic Pricing API](http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/current/Dynamic-Pricing-Configuration.html).    In the enterprise edition this includes support for rule based price lists.

Also, the framework is designed for extension allowing you to add new attributes to the domain as well as customizing and adding new services.

At current, it does not have any functionality for often requested B2B features like quotes, purchase orders, and EDI integrations.

Regards,

Brian

Comment: is the information still correct in regards to that last sentence?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Since the original post, Broadleaf has added a B2B edition.    It provides contract pricing, bulk ordering, quote management, and good starting points for punchout and vendor integrations.